# Creating a 'graphical' command line install for a Linux based OS package

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, package

Although I am relatively new to using Linux, I would like to know more on how deploying packages works. I have tried searching for this but have had no luck. I have seen countless packages and install scripts that use the same looking 'graphical' command line install for the user to select options for the package. Take the Debian net install for example. [1]

As I have a lot to learn, I would only like a summary of how this is possible, and any resources that anyone has on how developers do this.

Thanks in advance.

[1] http://doudoulinux.org/blog/public/screenshots/install/install-selected-tasks.png

Comment: A proper package for a linux distro should rather be available from the package manager.  Getting a package into the package manager is often far from trivial, it involves putting your package some review queue with the project team.  More often you can distribute non repository packages as `.deb` and `.rpm` (there's a lot of documentation on how to create these).  Personally, i consider [arch linux's AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) the simplest to create a package.  Also, graphical installers, even terminal based, are frowned upon in linux distros.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying how packages are made available to the public, but I think that you are wrong in your last statement, as a lot of distros do use graphical installers. I know that distros like gentoo and Arch have no graphical installers because of their target audience, but even then people still develop installers for them to make things easier. I am simply asking how they can be made, as it seems as if all command line graphical installers use the same base.

Comment: Apologies for my confusing phrase.  What i mean is that a **package itself** shall never contain any graphical installation.  As for the installers themselves they simply **call each other**.  Let's take debian for example, it uses `dpkg` but most people use `apt-get` which calls `dpkg` in the background.  There is the "curses graphical" `aptitude` (probably the first graphical package manager ever) which just calls `apt-get`.  And there's fully graphical `synaptic` which also calls `apt-get` behind the scenes.  In other words, when building a package one only cares about `dpkg/apt-get` info.

Comment: Ah okay thank you for that clarification. However I am still confused about I can use the installer screen that I want for a package, http://doudoulinux.org/blog/public/screenshots/install/install-selected-tasks.png This picture shows the format I want to find out how to use. Sorry if I am being stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now, i believe, i understand what you're after. I'll still insist that interactive configuration of packages is **distro specific** and shall not be the main form of package configuration.

It is preferred to ship in a default working configuration and then document how the user can change configuration files (normally in `/etc`) to reconfigure the package.  It is often useful to ship several default configurations (example package: [`wpa_supplicant`](https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/) which ships with several examples of network configuration, all disabled by default) and allow the user to choose by uncommenting lines.

---

### Debian

The `debian` specific way to get packages configured is `debconf`, its configuration is a simple `shell` script (or a `perl` script, or whatever else that can talk over `STDIN/STDOUT`) and a template file.  The template file is what will provide options in the `aptitude/apt-get` interface as in the screenshot in your question.

It is worth reading the [debian guidelines on package configuration](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch02.en.html#_package_configuration) to have an idea of which kind of configuration is too much.

And they also have a [thorough tutorial](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html).  Since you said you do not have experience packaging i also recommend reading [the introduction to packaging](https://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/Intro?action=show&redirect=IntroDebianPackaging), which will tell you where the files shall be placed.  Also, `dbhelper` is a great tool to place files in the correct place in the package directory.

---

### On other distros

Each distro has its own way of adding configuration to packages.  Debian is notable for its `debconf` as it is one of the most feature rich tools for configuring packages (together with `dpkg-reconfigure`).

Developers of the software that is sipped in a distro package are often different people from the ones that do the packaging.  Configuration options left by developers are often much more thorough than in the package (e.g. inclusion or exclusion of certain libraries).

The fact that you're most familiar with the `debian` distro (that is an assumption based on your question tags), might give you a misleading idea of package configuration.  Only debian based distros have so many configurable packages, other distros often use package dependencies to install differently configured packages.  For example:

- RedHat based distros (`.rpm` packages) have no tool such as `debconf` (as far as i am aware), they use distinct (conflicting) package names to install differently configured packages.
- Arch Linux based distros enforce the user configuration.  In essence, arch forces the user to configure their packages by going into their configuration files and changing the configuration (that is a very good thing if you want to learn).

Funny enough, both RPM and Arch based distros often ship `po-debconf`, an adapted `debconf` for that distro.  Yet, i cannot tell much about it since i never tried it.

Comment: Thank you, that answers my question. It seems I shouldn't have asked this kind of question before I have had experience in packaging.

Comment: Really, experience in packaging is about trying to do it.  If you follow a tutorial and take some two days to package a piece of software of your own into a distro package that shall be experience enough.  Making a package is not difficult, there are tools to help you along the way.  Getting a package included into an official repository is another story, yet there is hardly a need to do the former.